# Как получить все значения спарсеной HTML формы через PHP

Tags: php

Я паршу HTML форму с сайта. В даной HTML форме есть много полей как input(text, radio) так и textarea, select. И в спарсеной форме уже выставлены данные которые нужно отправить, мне нужно изменить только одно значение. Вопрос таков, можно ли как-то в массив записать все данные которые форма будет оправлять в случаи отправки формы в стандарте? Тоесть как в jquery seralize, такое сделать на PHP, чтоб я получил все данные всех полей которые будет отправлять форма.

Comment: [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php) ?

Comment: Мне в эту функцию просто запихнуть переменную с формой HTML?

Comment: В эту функцию передавать массив, а на выходе получите его сериализованное представление (строка).